Is it possible to only use USB-A data pins to communicate between two different devices and have an external power supply in parallel?
What I'm trying to do is charge my phone through USB-A QC but somehow use the data pins from the USB-A 2.0 to stablish communication with my car's infotainment system (Android Auto).
Why use an external power supply? The infotainment device has a very poor design and it doesn't have enough power to charge my phone and by connecting both through USB 2.0, my phone actually gets it's battery drained super fast.
That explained, I want to power my phone and be able to charge it while it is connected to Android Auto by a wired connection.
I don't want to rely on Bluetooth because the infotainment system is so bad, it doesn't always work.
I purchased a 12V USB-A and USB-C (both quick charge) charger. I also opened one up and tried connecting another USB-A 2.0 male cable to the pins of the female connector on the charger. In my head, this should work, as long as I keep the pin's order. Sadly, this is not the case. I tried using only the data pins, but it did not work, then I tried connecting the Vcc and GND pins, this also didn't work, but the male USB-A connector coming out from the charger, meant to stablish the Android Auto connection, got really hot, like if it was shorting out.
Then I tried using a small diode I had lying around, thinking it would help avoid current to flow in the direction of the infotainment system, but the diode started smoking really bad.
I'm clueless on what to do honestly. I don't understand how USB 2.0 data pins work. Do both devices meant to communicate need Vcc and GND pins in order to trigger communication or can they communicate without the power pins?
PS: While I was making this post I realized I totally messed up the pins. I was looking at the guide I was using the other way around, needed to flip it 180 degrees... I will try later today resoldering everything and post the results. I will also post this regardless of the outcome to get feedback on my little project here.






A USB hub with power?

I wanted to make it small in volume, mainly because of space restraints inside the car, but also to make it myself, I like doing this kind of stuff and learn in the process.

@MatiasMedves The learning process by doing may involve burning up your expensive phone and/or the car head unit as you already witnessed with the short circuits. To be fair, QuickCharge communication uses the same wires as USB data, and USB devices cannot be connected in parallel to same wires, so you cannot obviously transfer data with the head unit and at the same time get QuickCharge protocol to trigger higher voltage and power charging from the cigarette lighter plug charger. You cannot connect VBUS VCC pins together from two outputs. And USB does require detecting 5V before data comms.
